# Weird/Simple C error

Tags: c, function, types, double

I just started trying to learn C and have a pretty basic question. The code listed below outputs an error from the mult function stating that there are 'conflicting types for mult'

I can't see how there are any conflicting types. If I were to replace the data types of these values to ints however, I have no problems whatsoever. I'm assuming that I'm missing something very simple. Any help?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double number1;
    double answer;

    answer = mult(number1);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}

double mult(double x, double y)
{
  return x * y;
}
```

Comment: So, how do you explain the obvious issue: your `mult` function requires **two** arguments, while you are passing only **one**? Since you are the one who wrote the code, this issue should be immediately noticeable to you, shouldn't it? What did you try to achieve by calling two-parameter function with only one argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't declared `mult` before you use it, so the compiler implicitly declares it for you as `int mult()`. Then the compiler finds your definition and it doesn't match.

Try adding a prototype before your `main()`:

```
double mult(double, double);
```

Or just define it before `main()`.

Comment: Also he's calling the function with only one argument.

Comment: Repeating my comment on another answer: As of C99, there are no implicit function declarations; calling a function with no visible declaration is a constraint violation. (Many compilers just warn about it and fall back to C90 rules.)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems, one you are trying to use `mult` before it is declared, the one fix would be to forward declare `mult` before `main` like so:

```
double mult(double x, double y) ;
```

or just define `mult` before `main`, otherwise *C* pre-*C99* will implicitly define `mult` like this `int mult()` and in *C99* as Keith points out it is a constraint violation. The most recent versions of `clang` will warn you:

> implicit declaration of function 'mult' is invalid in C99

and `gcc` will just warn you that it is being implicitly declared, which is why you receive the type conflict. You are also trying to call `mult` with only one argument here:

```
answer = mult(number1);
```

but it is defined as taking two arguments. Finally you are using `number1` without initializing it which means it will have an indeterminate value.

Comment: As of C99, there are no implicit function declarations; calling a function with no visible declaration is a constraint violation. (Many compilers just warn about it and fall back to C90 rules.)

Comment: @KeithThompson yeah, I actually knew that and I should have mentioned it and I was actually using `clang` so it outright told me so.

Comment: This is one of many reasons why you shouldn't use old crap compilers when learning modern C programming.

Comment: @Lundin I don't follow, we don't know which compiler the OP is using and the latest version of `gcc` and `clang` just warn i.e. it is not an error or is this a more general statement?

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour If you forget the function prototype, a C99 compiler will detect it. But an old crap compiler will instead silently introduce "implicit int", which leads to unexpected bugs in most cases.